# What version of Tomcat is contained in the Websphere Application Server 7

Tags: tomcat, version, websphere-7

As far as I know the Websphere Application Server contains a Tomcat instance as servlet container.

I'd like to know which version of Tomcat this is in the Websphere 7.0 Version, since we are planning to use Tomcat for development, but WAS for deployment. Obviously we would like to use the matching version.

Comment: Tomcat is not the servlet container in WAS. Some components of Tomcat code base might be used in WAS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAS 7.0 is Java EE 5.0 compliant which covers under each JSP 2.1/Servlet 2.5, so it must be a [Tomcat 6.0.x](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) version.

Answer (score 3):

WebSphere Application Server v7 does not include Tomcat. It has its own implementation of the Servlet specification.